# Sum values in rows with same names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with some rows that are named the same as this (there are many more names other than those shown and many more columns wich names are variable):

```
          category1   category2 
bacteria      5           6
bacteria      3           6
bacteria      7           4
archaea       1           2
archaea       3           7
```

I need to sum the values of the rows that have the same to get an output like this:

```
          category1   category2 
bacteria      15          16
archaea       4           9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rowsum`.  Assume that the dataset showed is `matrix` and not `data.frame` as `data.frame` cannot have duplicated row names

```
rowsum(df1, row.names(df1))
```

---

Or using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df1, list(row.names(df1)), sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(c(5L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("bacteria", "bacteria", "bacteria", "archaea", 
"archaea"), c("category1", "category2")))
```